# "Global" event handler

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I've searched for a long time and cannot find the answer to this question. It might just be a matter of not knowing what to search for. Is it possible to have a "global" handler available for FrameworkElements?

For example:

On Page 1

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid1" Unloaded="GlobalHandler"/>
```

On Page 2

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid2" Unloaded="GlobalHandler"/>
```

Global handler? Where can I store this code so it's available for both Grids?

```
private void GlobalHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something with grid here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a static method with the same signature, then in your page, call the static method from your individual handlers.

```
public class EventHandlerHelper
{
  public static GlobalUnload(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    // work
  }
}

public class Page1
{
   public void GlobalHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      EventHandlerHelper.GlobalUnload(sender, e);
   }
}

public class Page2
{
   public void GlobalHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
      EventHandlerHelper.GlobalUnload(sender, e);
   }
}
```

Comment: the grids are on different Pages though

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I was wondering about something like this, but was still curious if there was a way to do it without having to call a static method each time. Oh well! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick a little more to XAML you can declare an `EventSetter` for a *style* in a `ResourceDictionary` and merge said dictionary into which ever Pages require it.

Straight from this [MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/601fca6c-17b8-4751-a0db-dfacd5ab5eac/reuse-of-handler-method-in-different-xaml-files) thanks to user [Kevin Pan](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/kevin%20pan/)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    x:Class="MyResource.MyResourceDictionary"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="mycanvasstyle">
    <EventSetter Event="Unloaded"Handler="MyResourceDictionary_GlobalHandler"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In the partial class for the `ResourceDictionary`

```
void MyResourceDictionary_GlobalHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something with grid here
}
```

And then add this to each Pages' XAML

```
<Page>
    <Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Page.Resources>

    <!-- rest of page -->

</Page>
```

Comment: I upvoted this. but this answer isn't valid for the question.  There is no `EventSetter` in Silverlight.